# Send radio button values to Controller Spring

Tags: java, html, spring

How can i pass these radio button values to my controller? I know i can use

```
(@RequestParam("radioButtonName") String radioButtonValue) {
```

But how could i use this if my "radioButtonNames" is always different? I have a lot of question and i am using foreach for this.

```
<table >
  <tr th:each="question : ${questions}">
    <!-- Question field -->
    <td  th:value="${question.qst_id}" th:text="${question.qst_title}"></td>
    <!-- Answer field -->
    <td th:text="${answers[0].answ_title}"></td>
    <td>
        <table >
            <tr>
            <td>1<input type="radio" th:name="${question.qst_id}" th:value="${answers[0].answ_id}"></td>
            <td>2<input type="radio" th:name="${question.qst_id}" th:value="${answers[1].answ_id}"></td>
            <td>3<input type="radio" th:name="${question.qst_id}" th:value="${answers[2].answ_id}"></td>
            <td>4<input type="radio" th:name="${question.qst_id}" th:value="${answers[3].answ_id}"></td>
            <td>5<input type="radio" th:name="${question.qst_id}" th:value="${answers[4].answ_id}"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </td>
    <td th:text="${answers[4].answ_title}"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><button type="submit">Save</button></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `th:field` for storing your radio button value and create a column of radio button in your model something like this.

```
<tr>
    <td><label for = "gender">Gender</label></td>
    <td><input type = "radio" name = "gender" th: field = "* {gender}" value = "male" />
    <label for = "radioA">Male</label>
    <input type = "radio" name = "gender" th: field = "* {gender}" value = "female" />
    <label for = "radioB">Women</label>
        </td>
</tr>
```